# Text carousel (multiple items on screen)

Tags: jquery, carousel, jcarousel

I need to create a slider for multiple text items on the screen.

To briefly describe functionality: the user clieks the left and right arrows and the names slide along. When the name is in the center position the relevant content panel is displayed. Clicking a name also brings it to the center and shows the content panel (though this last bit is optional).

I've just built one using jCarousel but it's a bit hacky so I was wondering whether there are any other carousel plugins which could handle it better (the most important things are the ability to add a class to the middle item to make it larger, the ability to trigger an event so that a panel is loaded when an item comes to the center position and the ability to display multiple items on the screen at the same time).

I also need to make it responsive but I can work on this later... if no suitable plugins immediately spring to mind I'll add a link to the version which I've built and see if there is any way that we can repair it.

Thanks :)

[image: prototype]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I was able to create this using Caroufredslider.

I won't post the code here as it's quite application-specific but I'm happy to share if anyone would find it useful.